# Can I upgrade a docker image/container from buntu 18.04 to ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: docker, containers, linux, ubuntu

I have a host ubuntu 20.04 running my software on docker with a container derivated from ubuntu 18.04. I would like to use ubuntu 20.04 for several reasons (like the better software on 20.04).
If I run do-release-upgrade on the container terminal I receive the following:
"do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
You have not rebooted after updating a package which requires a reboot. Please reboot before upgrading."
Rebooting the container or rebooting the host machine does not solve the problem.

Comment: if you have the dockerfile, and you are able to rebuild the image, you could just change the `FROM:ubuntu` command at the top of the dockerfile. You can use tags such as `latest` or pin it to a specific version

Answer (score 1):

Docker doesn't recommend running an apt-get upgrade and dist-upgrade on a docker image as many of the "essential" packages from the partent image cannot upgrade inside an unprevileged container. take a look at the [Docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Answer (score 0):

That is not good design to have docker or any lib update after logging into the container. As mentioned by Andrea Giaime Bodei , you need to update the base image in the Dockerfile and rebuild the image. The docker images are immutable.

```
# Download base image ubuntu 20.04
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# LABEL about the custom image
LABEL maintainer="abcd@me.com"
LABEL version="0.1"
LABEL description="This is custom Docker Image for \
the test"
```